# How do I enable a group of users to edit files in Ubuntu var/www?

Tags: ubuntu, chown, www-data, chgrp

I'm hoping someone will be able to direct or help me understand how I can enable multiple users to edit the same files/folders in Ubuntu EC2 server (11.10).

I currently use Transmit, the Terminal window, and Wordpress to upload files to the WP folder. To use WP from it's "Dashboard panel" I find I have to `chown` the WP directory to the `www-data` user and whenever I want to upload files through Transmit to the WP directory I have to `chown` to the `ubuntu` user to allow this to happen.

I've tried `chgrp` to the WP folder upon adding `www-data` and `ubuntu` to a common group, but it still doesn't allow each user to edit/delete files without `chown`.

How can I allow a group of users in Ubuntu to be able to edit/delete files in the same directory?

Thanks for your help,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the [set-Group-ID](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html) bit on a directory files created in that directory will inherit the same group as the directory.

If your umask is set to allow members of the group to edit files this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Bram for your response. I'll change the set-Group-ID for the files and edit umask details for users. Thanks!

Comment: I found [this link](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilesp.html) where files and dir permissions are much better explained, incl umask.